# FAQ page access denied for anonymous users

Tags: users, 7

I've installed the [FAQ module](https://drupal.org/project/faq) and created some FAQ content. The FAQ page is found here: http://www.inadaydevelopment.com/faq-page

I have given Anonymous users the "View FAQ pages" permission, but anonymous users still cannot view the FAQ content of the above page. It shows the header block which I configured to appear only on that page, but the body of the page shows Access Denied.

What am I missing?

Comment: I can see the page as anonymous user.

Comment: I know you can see the top block which talks about customer support, but do you see the FAQ questions below that? What is the text of the first question?

Comment: It looks like I needed to flush my cache, the page was cached with old permissions and so anon couldn't see it last night when I made the change, but can see it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I needed to flush my cache, the page was cached with old permissions and so anon couldn't see it last night when I made the change, but can see it now.